# How do you get the current stacktrace in Dart for a Completer.CompleteException(exception, stackTrace);

Tags: dart, dart-async

If some code returns a future and determines that the future should return "Error" or "Exception" how can a stack trace be passed to `Completer.completeException(exception, stackTrace);`

Answer (score 209, accepted):

If I understand correctly: when you catch an exception in dart, you can also catch the stack trace:

```dart
try {
  // something
} catch(e, stacktrace) {
  myCompleter.completeException(e, stacktrace);
}
```

Comment: To add to this, if you don't have a current exception, just throw one in the try block and catch it yourself.

Comment: Hey, Adam, that sounds like a pretty good answer. You might want to green checkmark it :)

Comment: John's answer is correct, the answer I was looking for is Justin's.

Comment: @JustinFagnani why don't you go ahead and make a separate answer since it was closer to what Adam was looking for. :)

Comment: Where do we get ```myCompleter``` from?

Answer (score 191):

If you're not in a catch block, you can use [`StackTrace.current`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-core/StackTrace/current.html)

Comment: This is useful if you need to get a stack trace from any arbitrary location, but if you're within a `catch` block, the chosen answer is better since Dart already provides a `StackTrace` to you.