# How to get stacktrace from Flutter?

Tags: flutter, stack-trace

I have a Android/iOS app developed using `Flutter` through Visual Studio Code. When I run it on Android >=5.0 or any version of iOS it works flawlessly, however **it crashes immediately** when I run it on Android 4.x (*Unfortunately, app has stopped*).

I want to fix it, but `Flutter`doesn't show me what is happening.

I tried to run through VSCode pushing F5 button and also using command line `flutter run`, but neither shows me something that I could work with. I tried to run with `trace` command `[Flutter trace run]`, but it says `The --debug-port argument must be specified` and I don't know what it means.

I just need a stacktrace or a line error showing me what is the problem. Do I have to configure something on VSCode?

Comment: For Flutter code you can use https://github.com/flutter/sentry. For iOS you can try 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20998#issuecomment-418845807 for Android running `adb logcat` while the app is run should provide more details.

Comment: You could work around it, and read the logs directly from the device with the command `adb logcat` https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat

Comment: Thanks Günter and Blundell! Using logcat I found `Exception thrown during pause android.os.DeadObjectException`. No idea how to fix it, but now I can work with it.

Comment: For android you can type in the terminal `cd android` and then `./gradlew build --stacktrace`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you get the current stacktrace in Dart for a Completer.CompleteException(exception, stackTrace);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963837/how-do-you-get-the-current-stacktrace-in-dart-for-a-completer-completeexception)

Comment: You can use `StackTrace.current`  - I think this question is a duplicate of this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963837/how-do-you-get-the-current-stacktrace-in-dart-for-a-completer-completeexception - either way, the answer I have given is there.

Answer (score 2):

There's a Debug Console available in Visual Studio Code as per checking version 1.51.1. This can be enabled/disabled by navigating through the menu `View > Debug Console`. Both logs from Android emulator and iOS simulator can be displayed on the Debug Console.

[image]

However, if you're looking into checking Flutter debug logs outside of Visual Studio Code, the [`adb logcat`](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) command using the terminal works well for Android as previously mentioned in the comments.

On iOS, one way of checking the logs is through the Console. Press ⌘ + space and type "Console", and press Enter to launch the app. The iOS device should be displayed on the left-side pane of the Console app under `Devices`. Clicking on the iOS device should display its logs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Run the app with `flutter run --verbose` in the console and you'll get the complete stack trace.