# Flutter exceptions thrown but only one line is shown

Tags: flutter, debugging, dart, exception, runtime-error

Anyone know why when Flutter throws an exception only one line is shown?
At the moment I'm running my app using BLoC, and the only code generator that we use is JsonSerializer

Comment: I think you might be looking for the stack trace? See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/13964402 if so

Comment: You're right - the entire stack trace is not printing.
The problem is that I don't use completer anywhere to be seen. Do you know where it might be the case?